# Publish Major Version Comment access in SPD workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, versioning, comments

When publishing a major version of a document, SharePoint prompts the user for comments on their changes. These comments seem to appear in the "Check In Comments" column.

Is there a way to capture this in a SharePoint Designer workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform in SharePoint Designer.
[image]

Then you can find the Check in Comments field under the current item data source.

[image]