# Check in comment field in workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, workflow2013

I know how to get "Check in comment" field through "workflow 2010" [Publish Major Version Comment access in SPD workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/publish-major-version-comment-access-in-spd-workflow/242191#242191).

But in "workflow 2013" this field is missing. Is there any way to do this with "workflow 2013"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers, next solution did the job for me:

First I found this article "[How to Get the Check-in Comments of the File in SharePoint 2013 Online Using REST API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-the-check-in-comment-of-the-file-in-sharepoint-20/)" for FLOW.
It helped me to implement "[Calling the SHarepoint 2013 REST API from a Sharepoint Designer workflow](https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/)".

I will not describe how to find and check the query in browser.

To get "Check in comment" you need do next steps:

1. Add "Build" action to the "Stage".
2. Rename the dictionary variable to "JSonRequestHeader".
3. Click "this", then click "Build your dictionnary"; add "Accept" and "Content-Type" headers, with type "String" and value "application/json;odata=verbose".
4. Next add "Call" action.
5. Click "this" and paste your http request like `https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('[%Current Item:Server Relative URL%]')/CheckInComment`
6. To associate the "JSonRequestHeader" variable select "Call" action property (To the right of the action down arrow).
7. Set "RequestHeaders" property to "JSonRequestHeader".
8. In "Call" action, click "response" and associate the response to a new variable: "JSonResult" (of type Dictionary).
9. After "Call" action add a new "Get" action: click "item by name or path" and add `"d/CheckInComment`" then click "dictionary" and choose "JSonResult" then click "item" and choose your variable for value from "Check in comment" field.

Comment: Yes, we can also use REST API to get this data, thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, as a workaround, we can start a SharePoint 2010 workflow in workflow 2013 to get this data.

Refer to: [How to trigger a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I considered this option, but I wanted to do this as part of the "workflow 2013".